# How to do a conditional Sum with Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, queryover, nhibernate-3

I'm trying to do the equivalent of this SQL Code

```
SELECT 
ID
SUM(CASE WHEN myProperty = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nbRowWithValueOf2,
SUM(CASE WHEN myProperty = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nbRowWithValueOf3
FROM Foo
GROUP BY ID
```

With Nhibernate.

So far I tried

```
queryable = queryable
    .Select(
        Projections.Group<Foo>(c => c.ID),
        Projections.Sum<Foo>(c => c.myProperty == MyEnum.Two ? 1 : 0)
        Projections.Sum<Foo>(c => c.myProperty == MyEnum.Three ? 1 : 0)
)
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Could not determine member from IIF((Convert(c.myProperty) = 2), 1, 0)

Do you have any idea ?

EDIT 1 : I can get the result with 2 queries but I want to do this in only 1 query.

EDIT 2 : I'm using QueryOver here.

Comment: It looks like you should probably use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`.

Comment: Count doesn't accept conditions, how could I use it here ? Two queries ?

Comment: If it doesn't accept queries, you could use `WHERE` to select only the ones you want to count, and then use `COUNT`.

Comment: So that's Two queries, one for the rows with the value MyEnum.Two and one for the rows with the value MyEnum.Three. That's definitely working, but I prefer to do this in only one query.

Comment: One query. Check if value == MyEnum.Two `OR` value == MyEnum.Three

Comment: Which you could probably do using `SUM`. Why have you written them separately, anyway?

Comment: Can you post the full code ? I'm not sure but I think you didn't get what I asked.

Comment: Aer you using QueryOver?

Comment: @Jim, because I want them separately. I want to know how many records have a value of two and how many have the value of Three !

Comment: Alright I think I see what you are asking now. You would like to display one column that shows the number of elements with value==2 and one column with the number of elements with value==3. Since those are two different cases producing separate results, you will need 2 queries

Comment: @Jim, I showed the SQL needed for this kind of results so I guess this should work with NH too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this should work (QueryOver syntax):

```
queryover = queryover
    .Select(
        Projections.Group<Foo>(c => c.ID),
        Projections.Sum(
            Projections.Conditional(
                Restrictions.Where<Foo>(f => f.myProperty == MyEnum.Two),
                Projections.Constant(1),
                Projections.Constant(0))),
        Projections.Sum(
            Projections.Conditional(
                Restrictions.Where<Foo>(f => f.myProperty == MyEnum.Three),
                Projections.Constant(1),
                Projections.Constant(0))));
```

Which should give you the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT this_.ID as y0_,
       sum((case
              when this_.myProperty = 2 /* @p0 */ then 1 /* @p1 */
              else 0 /* @p2 */
            end))               as y1_,
       sum((case
              when this_.myProperty = 3 /* @p3 */ then 1 /* @p4 */
              else 0 /* @p5 */
            end))               as y2_
FROM   [Foo] this_
GROUP  BY this_.ID
```

Comment: Do you know how this will look like if I use QueryOver instead?

Comment: I mean using SelectGroup instead of Projections.Group, SelectSum instead of Projections.Sum and so on, so QueryOver with inline syntax to be precise with terms

Comment: The problem is that there's no inline syntax for `Projections.Conditional`. You have to drop back into criteria for the `case when x then y end`.

Comment: The problem with QueryOver is that it doesn't support Any in its where clause

Comment: @Beatles1692: What do you mean exactly? Do you mean generating an `any` clause in the generated SQL? If so, this is possible with the `WithSubquery.WhereSome`. If you mean using LINQ's `.Any` extension method, no that probably won't work because LINQ syntax isn't the same as the QueryOver API

Comment: Yes I was talking about the latter.Where we can have Any in our Where clause but it's not possible in a QueryOver.